# nested ul li out of position

Tags: html, css

I created small nav menu which will hold another options. The li element needs to be opened and another list appears. Unfortunately my nested list appears next to the parent li instead of below. Meanwhile I tweaked there and here and can´t find my problem, it must be something so simple which I do not see anymore.

I appreciate any hints.

```js
  var icon = document.getElementById("main-menu-button");
    var icon1 = document.getElementById("icon-top");
    var icon2 = document.getElementById("icon-middle");
    var icon3 = document.getElementById("icon-bottom");
    var nav = document.getElementById('main-menu');

    icon.addEventListener('click', function() {
    icon1.classList.toggle('icon-top');
    icon2.classList.toggle('icon-middle');
    icon3.classList.toggle('icon-bottom');
    nav.classList.toggle('show');
    });


    $('.main-menu-ul ul').hide();
    
    $('.main-menu-li').click(function() {
        $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
    });
```

```css
   .icon-1, .icon-2, .icon-3 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 32px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: black;
    transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(.84,.06,.52,1.8);
}

.icon-1 {
    transform: translateY(-8px);
    animation-delay: 100ms;
}
  
.icon-3 {
    transform: translateY(8px);
    animation-delay: 250ms;
}

.icon-1.icon-top {
    transform: rotate(40deg);
}

.icon-2.icon-middle {
    transform: rotate(-40deg);
}

.icon-3.icon-bottom {
    opacity: 0;
}

.hamburger-icon {
    position: absolute;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    top: 2%;
    left: 1%;
    z-index: 1000;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.hamburger-icon:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.dark-blue {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #003273;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.04, 0.3, 1.8);
    transition-delay: 50ms;
    z-index: 5;
    opacity: 0;
}
  
.dark-blue.slide {
    width: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
}

h1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 2%;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #757575;
}

nav {
    background: whitesmoke;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0;
    box-shadow: -3px -3px 10px rgba(70,70,70,0.12), 
    3px 3px 15px rgba(70,70,70,0.12);
    transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.04, 0.3, 1.56);
    transition-delay: 100ms;
}

nav.show {
    width: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
}

.main-menu-ul {
    position: relative;
    height: fit-content;
    list-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #757575;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: -10px -10px 10px rgba(255,255,255,0.5), 
                 15px 15px 15px rgba(70,70,70,0.12);
    margin: 5vh 10px 10px 10px;
}

.main-menu-li {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 5vh;
    height: fit-content;
    color: #757575;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
}

.main-menu-li:hover {
    transform: scale3d(1.05);
}

.span-left {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
}

.span-middle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60%;
}

.span-right {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 20%;
}

.sub-menu-ul {
   display: inline-block;
   float: none;
   height: 0;
   border: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
        <title>UL Test</title>    
        <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/98a5e27706.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <!-- NAV Begin -->
     <div class="hamburger-icon" id="main-menu-button">
        <div class="icon-1" id="icon-top"></div>
        <div class="icon-2" id="icon-middle"></div>
        <div class="icon-3" id="icon-bottom"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>


<nav id="main-menu">
    <h1>Test</h1>
    
    <ul class="main-menu-ul">
        <li class="main-menu-li">
            <span class="span-left"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i></span>
            <span class="span-middle">Login</span>
            <span class="span-right"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></span>
                <ul class="sub-menu-ul">
                    <li>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password"> 
                    </li>        
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main-menu-li">
            <span class="span-left"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></span>
            <span class="span-middle">Search</span>
            <span class="span-right"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></span>
        </li>
        <li class="main-menu-li">
            <span class="span-left"><i class="fa-solid fa-mountain-sun"></i></span>
            <span class="span-middle">Display Settings</span>
            <span class="span-right"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></span>
        </li>
        <li class="main-menu-li">
            <span class="span-left"><i class="fa-solid fa-gears"></i></span>
            <span class="span-middle">General Settings</span>
            <span class="span-right"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></span>
        </li>
        <li class="main-menu-li">
            <span class="span-left"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-export"></i></span>
            <span class="span-middle">Export</span>
            <span class="span-right"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></span>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="main-menu-ul">
        <li class="main-menu-li">
            <span class="span-left"><i class="fa-solid fa-info"></i></span>
            <span class="span-middle">Info</span>
            <span class="span-right"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Also look at your hamburger on a small screen. I think the font's too big

Comment: Of course it is not adjusted for differenz screen sizes yet, still thanks for the hint I will correct that soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem related to the flexbox. All elements under `main-menu-li` are flex items including your sub `ul`.

For a fix, you should separate those elements in `main-menu-li` by divs and set flexboxes for divs instead.

```js
var icon = document.getElementById("main-menu-button");
var icon1 = document.getElementById("icon-top");
var icon2 = document.getElementById("icon-middle");
var icon3 = document.getElementById("icon-bottom");
var nav = document.getElementById('main-menu');

icon.addEventListener('click', function() {
  icon1.classList.toggle('icon-top');
  icon2.classList.toggle('icon-middle');
  icon3.classList.toggle('icon-bottom');
  nav.classList.toggle('show');
});


$('.main-menu-ul ul').hide();

$('.main-menu-li').click(function() {
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.icon-1,
.icon-2,
.icon-3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 32px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(.84, .06, .52, 1.8);
}

.icon-1 {
  transform: translateY(-8px);
  animation-delay: 100ms;
}

.icon-3 {
  transform: translateY(8px);
  animation-delay: 250ms;
}

.icon-1.icon-top {
  transform: rotate(40deg);
}

.icon-2.icon-middle {
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
}

.icon-3.icon-bottom {
  opacity: 0;
}

.hamburger-icon {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  top: 2%;
  left: 1%;
  z-index: 1000;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.hamburger-icon:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.dark-blue {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #003273;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.04, 0.3, 1.8);
  transition-delay: 50ms;
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 0;
}

.dark-blue.slide {
  width: 25%;
  opacity: 1;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 2%;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #757575;
}

nav {
  background: whitesmoke;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0%;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: -3px -3px 10px rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.12),
    3px 3px 15px rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.12);
  transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.62, 0.04, 0.3, 1.56);
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}

nav.show {
  width: 25%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.main-menu-ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  /*display: flex;*/ /*Remove this*/
  height: fit-content;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #757575;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: -10px -10px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5),
    15px 15px 15px rgba(70, 70, 70, 0.12);
  margin: 5vh 10px 10px 10px;
}

.main-menu-li {
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 5vh;
  height: fit-content;
  color: #757575;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}

/*Added a wrapper with div and made it become flexbox*/
.main-menu-li div {
  display: flex;
}

.main-menu-li:hover {
  transform: scale3d(1.05);
}

.span-left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}

.span-middle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
}

.span-right {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 20%;
}

.sub-menu-ul {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  height: 0;
  border: none;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  <title>UL Test</title>
  <!-- fontawesome stylesheet https://fontawesome.com/ -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/98a5e27706.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- NAV Begin -->
  <div class="hamburger-icon" id="main-menu-button">
    <div class="icon-1" id="icon-top"></div>
    <div class="icon-2" id="icon-middle"></div>
    <div class="icon-3" id="icon-bottom"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>


  <nav id="main-menu">
    <h1>Test</h1>

    <ul class="main-menu-ul">
      <li class="main-menu-li">
        <div>
          <span class="span-left"><i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i></span>
          <span class="span-middle">Login</span>
          <span class="span-right"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></span>
        </div>
        <ul class="sub-menu-ul">
          <li>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="main-menu-li">
        <div>


          <span class="span-left"><i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i></span>
          <span class="span-middle">Search</span>
          <span class="span-right"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="main-menu-li">
        <div>


          <span class="span-left"><i class="fa-solid fa-mountain-sun"></i></span>
          <span class="span-middle">Display Settings</span>
          <span class="span-right"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="main-menu-li">
        <div>


          <span class="span-left"><i class="fa-solid fa-gears"></i></span>
          <span class="span-middle">General Settings</span>
          <span class="span-right"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="main-menu-li">
        <div>


          <span class="span-left"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-export"></i></span>
          <span class="span-middle">Export</span>
          <span class="span-right"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></span>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>

    <ul class="main-menu-ul">
      <li class="main-menu-li">
        <div>


          <span class="span-left"><i class="fa-solid fa-info"></i></span>
          <span class="span-middle">Info</span>
          <span class="span-right"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```